# Magento 2.1: grid list in admin: data displayed but still the "loading" animation

Tags: adminhtml, grid, magento-2.1

I created three grids in the back end of a Magento 2.1 admin. The two first a working properly, but there is a little problem with the last one: while the data are displayed in the list, there is still the loading animation on the front overlay.

**Note 1:** With Chrome I can hide this overlay and I can normaly use the grid.

**Note 2:** The two working grids have very few lines (37 and 110 respectively) while the problematic one has ~38000 lines. Even with the pagination, I have this problem.

[image]

Comment: You can try with remove var folder, remove pub/static folder and run deploy command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and in last clear browser cache

Comment: I tried: emptied var/.., deleteted pub/static, redeployed, emptied browser cache. Same thing infortunately...